# How to change connection string in web.config based on environment it's being run in?

Tags: iis, web-config, azure-devops, web.config-transform

I'm using visual studio team services and I use their build process to build and push code to our development server. The problem is the web.config has my localhost connection string and the dev server connection string commented out. How can I set up the web.config and the build process to use the correct connection string?

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace specific value in a file (e.g. web.config) through [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) during the build or release in VSTS.

For example:

[image]

For this configuration of Replace Token task, it can replace #{con}# to the con variable value (Create a variable (variable name: con) in Variable tab of build definition) for all .config files (have #{con}# code) in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) location.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="#{con}#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Because connectionString value is token, how a developer will run/debug this locally. They always need to go through build-release pipeline to run ?

Answer (score -1):

web.config transformation does this based on the Build in the congifuration manager.

1) add the additional files (web.config.debug, web.config.release)

2) add the markup in the config files

```
 <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Build-time web.config transforms encourage build-per-deployment, which is a bad practice.